# Is it possible to "override" just the workflow from a product?

Tags: plone

I have `mynamespace.myproduct` and `mynamespace.myproduct2`.

`mynamespace.myproduct2` is defined as a dependency in `mynamespace.myproduct`'s `metadata.xml`. `mynamespace.myproduct2` has some workflows that I would like to override, without having to customize `mynamespace.myproduct2` as a whole.

I know I can change it using the `portal_workflow` at ZMI, but I need to keep these changes, in both situations when `mynamespace.myproduct` and `mynamespace.myproduct2` are reinstalled in `portal_quickinstaller`.

The workflows would have the same name, but my customized one will have different states, and I need `mynamespace.myproduct` to override `mynamespace.myproduct2`'s workflows. Summarizing: I need to just change a workflow from a product, (keeping the content-types, etc) but don't want to customize the whole package.

I tought about overrides.zcml (an [example](http://dev.communesplone.org/trac/browser/communesplone/MeetingTubize/trunk/plone25/MeetingTubize/overrides.zcml)), but this overrides the profile completely, and I just want to override the workflow (and dont even know if this approach works. adding this file is going to be always used instead of the original profile? How do I properly test it?). And according to [plone community guide](http://readthedocs.org/docs/collective-docs/en/latest/components/genericsetup.html):

> Note Difference between ZCML and GenericSetup ZCML changes affect
>   loaded Python code in all sites inside Zope whereas GenericSetup XML
>   files affect only one Plone site and its database. GenericSetup XML
>   files are always database changes. Relationship between ZCML and
>   site-specific behavior is usually done using layers. ZCML directives,
>   like viewlets and views, are registered to be active on a certain
>   layer only using layer attribute. When GenericSetup XML is imported
>   through portal_setup, or the product add-on installer is run for a
>   Plone site, the layer is activated for the particular site only,
>   enabling all views registered for this layer.

I don't want this to affect all Plone sites, just one.

So, is this possible/feasible, or will I have to do a fork and edit the xml files from the original workflow to work?

Answer (score 4):

to override any workflow defined in `mynamespace.myproduct2` you have to add a new workflow definition in `mynamespace.myproduct` and bind it to your desired content type.

So you have to add this structure:

```
<myproduct>/
|-- ...
`-- profiles/
   `-- default/
      |-- ...
      |-- workflows.xml
      `-- workflows/
         `-- mycustom_workflow/
            `-- definition.xml
```

and in `workflows.xml` you will have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_workflow" meta_type="Plone Workflow Tool">

 <!-- This registers the new workflow -->
 <object name="mycustom_workflow" meta_type="Workflow"/>

 <!-- This binds the new wf with MyContent content type -->    
 <bindings>
   <type type_id="MyContent">
     <bound-workflow workflow_id="mycustom_workflow"/>
   </type>
 </bindings>

</object>
```

This will affect only the site where your product is installed.
In the end remember to restart zope and to re-install your product to apply the new genericsetup configuration.

Comment: But if I install `mynamespace.myproduct2` (the dependecy), it's going to "override the override". How do I avoid this?

Comment: You cannot...simply reinstall your product with the overrides as the last one